# regex matching in ruby confusion

Tags: ruby, regex, string, string-matching

Can anyone explain this to me?

```
str = "org-id:         N/A\n"

puts str[/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/]
=> "org-id:         N/A\n"
str =~ /org-id:\s+(.+)\n/
puts $1
=> "N/A"
```

All I need is

```
str =~ /org-id:\s+(.+)\n/
puts $1
```

in one line.
But `str[/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/]` and `str.slice(/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/)` return `"org-id:         N/A\n"` and str.scan(/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/).first returns `["N/A"]` (and array). Why are all this matchings acting differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [fine manual](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-5B-5D):

> **str[regexp] → new_str or nil**
>   **str[regexp, fixnum] → new_str or nil**
>
> If a `Regexp` is supplied, the matching portion of *str* is returned. If a numeric or name parameter follows the regular expression, that component of the `MatchData` is returned instead.

So, if you do `str[/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/]` then you get the entire matching portion (AKA `$&`); if you want the first capture group (AKA `$1`), then you could say:

```
puts str[/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/, 1]
# 'N/A'
```

If you had a second capture group in your regex and you wanted what it captured, you could say `str[regex, 2]` and so on. You could also use a named capture group and a symbol thusly:

```
puts str[/org-id:\s+(?<want>.+)\n/, :want]
```

So with the right pattern and arguments, `String#[]` is convenient for pulling a single regex-based chunk out of a string.

If you look at the manual you should notice that `String#[]` and `String#splice` are the same thing.

---

If we look at [`String#=~`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), we see that:

> **str =~ obj → fixnum or nil**
>
> Match—If *obj* is a `Regexp`, use it as a pattern to match against *str*, and returns the position the match starts, or `nil` if there is no match.

So when you say:

```
str =~ /org-id:\s+(.+)\n/
```

you get `'org-id:         N/A'` in `$&`, `'N/A'` in `$1`, and the operator's return value is the number zero; if there was another capture group in your regex, you'd see that part in `$2`. The "`nil` or not `nil`" return value of `=~` allows you to say things like:

```
make_pancakes_for($1) if(str =~ /some pattern that makes (us) happy/)
```

So `=~` is convenient for combining parsing and boolean tests in one go.

---

The [`String#scan`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-scan) method:

> **scan(pattern) → array**
>   **scan(pattern) {|match, ...| block } → str**
>
> Both forms iterate through *str*, matching the pattern (which may be a `Regexp` or a `String`). For each match, a result is generated and either added to the result array or passed to the block. If the pattern contains no groups, each individual result consists of the matched string, `$&`. If the pattern contains groups, each individual result is itself an array containing one entry per group.

So `scan` gives you a simple list of matches or an AoA of matches if capture groups are involved and `scan` is meant to pull apart a string into all its component pieces in one go (sort of like a more complicated version of [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split)).

If you wanted to grab all of the `(.+)` matches from your string you'd use `scan` and [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map):

```
array_of_ids = str.scan(/org-id:\s+(.+)\n/).map(&:first)
```

but you'd only bother with that if you knew there would be several org-ids in `str`. Scan will also leave `$&`, `$1`, ... set to the values for the last match in the `scan`; but if you're using `scan` you'll be looking for several matches at once so those globals won't be terribly useful.

---

The three regex approaches (`[]`, `=~`, and `scan`) offer similar functionality but they fill different niches. You could do it all with `scan` but that would be pointlessly cumbersome unless you were an orthogonality bigot and then you certainly wouldn't be working in Ruby except under extreme duress so it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between a match and a capture. Str[regex] returns the whole of the fragment matching the whole of the regex. $1 represents only the part of the match which is captured by the first () clause.